# How To Force Thread Change in ASP.NET Core ProcessAsync in Tag Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, tag-helpers

I'm trying to put a demonstration together to show that ProcessAsync moves the work off of the currently running ASP.NET Web Server thread pool.  I wrote a short example that calls a weather service.  Unfortunately the threadId does not change.

My understanding is that it might not.  So, two questions:

1:  Am I doing this correctly and should I expect that ThreadIdBefore and ThreadIdAfter should/might be different?

2: Assuming I'm doing this correctly, Is there something I can do to make the demo show a new threadId?

```
namespace WebAppTagHelper.TagHelpers
{
    public class MyTestTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private static HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

        string requestUrl = "http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=35&lon=139&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1";
        public override async Task ProcessAsync(
            TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var threadIdBefore = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            var uri = new Uri(requestUrl);
            using (var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri))
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                JObject json = JObject.Parse(result);
                if (result != null)
                {
                    output.Attributes.Add("class", "highlight");
                    var threadIdAfter = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
                    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(
                        string.Format("<b>Thread ID Before: {0} After: {1}</b>", threadIdBefore, threadIdAfter));

                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Async method will continue execution on first available thread, in your case first thread is happened to be same. You can maybe achive this by sending multiple requests simultaneously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I doing this correctly and should I expect that ThreadIdBefore and ThreadIdAfter should/might be different?

No. There's no `await` between the "before" and "after", so there's no possibility of a thread change.

Comment: Thanks @stephen-cleary   Good catch.  I've fixed the source and still get the same threadId as a result.  Any straight forward way to force it on to a new thread you can think of?

Comment: Other than `Task.Run`? Why would you want to?

Comment: Just for teaching.  How can I show that the async work is happening on a thread outside the active web thread pool.

Comment: @Evk help me learn.  please let me know what you are seeing that makes it clear I don't understand.

Comment: @PeterKellner: I have an [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and an [intro to async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) that may help you.

Comment: Thanks @StephenCleary, I've read both and both very helpful to my understanding.  I will review again.  BTW, I did move the location of threadIdBefore and the id's show different now.  Can you help me understand why Evk made the above comment?

Comment: This statement for example is not correct: "ProcessAsync moves the work off of the currently running ASP.NET Web Server thread pool". Both threads involved are from the same thread pool.

Comment: @StephenCleary I think I understand but this sentence in your article confuses me: "The important difference is that the request thread has been returned to the thread pool while the asynchronous call is in progress.". How can it be returned to some place that it is already?

Comment: It is a thread pool thread, but when it's not running code (i.e., when it `await`s), it is no longer allocated to that request.